# Input type number burlado

Tags: php, html, laravel

Les vengo con una pregunta un poco fácil a ver quién me puede responder.

Yo tengo un input type number normal con sus dos flechas para aumentar y para disminuir limitado de mínimo 1 y de máximo cien;

```html
    <input
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="100" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" id="product_{{ $item->id }}"
    >
        <a 
        href="#" 
        class="btn btn-warning btn-update-item"
        data-href="{{ route('cart-update', $item->slug) }}"
        data-id = "{{ $item->id }}">
                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
        </a>
```

El problema resultó después de que alguien simplemente colocara el cursor dentro del `input` y comenzara a escribir letras y números; entonces me salen un montón de errores con las letras y con los números no sale ningún error, pero después no me deja avanzar en otras funciones al tener más del número máximo.

¿Existe alguna manera de que ningún usuario pueda editar esta línea de manera forzada?

Answer (score 3):

Respuesta corta: **no, es imposible garantizar lo que pides**.

Piensa que el usuario tiene **mil y una** formas de *saltarse* lo que tu pretendes. Desde utilizar navegadores antiguos, hasta realizar el mismo la consulta mediante herramientas externas, como `wget`. Pasando por, sencillamente, abrir el código fuente de la página, editar el campo, y eliminar cualquier posible limitación que exista.

Resumiendo: **nunca**, **jamás de los jamases**, **bajo ningún motivo o circunstancia**, confíes en que vas a recibir *exactamente* lo que quieres recibir. **Comprueba** la validez de los datos **SIEMPRE**.

Esto es una regla **de oro** en cualquier lenguaje, programa o tecnología. Programa siempre a la defensiva, como si el usuario **intentara por todos los medios a su alcance** *romper* tu programa.

Comment: Programación defensiva: una obligación ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si fue posible amigos, mediante una funcion de javascript

> if(quantity < 1 || quantity > 100 ) {
>           // show some error using jquery
>
> ```
>       var message ='Solo Numeros y No mayor a cien';
>         alert(message);
>         return true;
>
>      }
> ```

me sorprende que nadie de aqui haya podido responder esta pregunta.

En general nadie responde a mis preguntas, pero algo tan facil como esto me deja sorprendido en mala manera.

Gracias por sus comentarios!
Saludos!

Comment: **Nadie** te respondió porque, sencillamente, **no preguntas bien**. De tu pregunta, yo entiendo que quieres **garantizar** una entrada **del lado del cliente**, y eso es **imposible**. En lo que muestras, no se tarda ni 3 segundos en saltarse tu control; basta con guardar la página y editarla. Si nadie mas te respondió, es **porqué todos entendieron lo mismo**.